How to implement liblinphone in Windows Form App using C#
I have a Windows Form App with a Webview running a "Softphone" based on HTML/JS and WEBRTC (Janus).
Now i want to implement the telephony functions native in the app by using liblinphone SDK. Everything seems ok so far, but i don't know where to place
CoreService.CoreStart(Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.Dispatcher);

In my tests with an UWP-App i've done this in
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)

in the App.xaml.cs, but in the Form-App (.NET6) there are no such overrides.
I'm using the LinphoneSDK.Windows 5.3.91 as NuGet-Package.
